# Papa.parse componentDidMount shouldComponentUpdate confusion

Tags: reactjs, papaparse

Edit: I think this is a CORS issue with codesandbox, but I haven't figured out how to host with static ip or even localhost yet.  I'll update when I can confirm it is a CORS issue between papaparse and codesandbox cloud ide. I started a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879616/papaparse-doesnt-work-for-more-than-1-mb-for-me-react) for a different problem than Domino solved here on the same papaparse application

This question here on StackOverflow is an extension of my conversation with [Papa.parse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse/issues/701).

A pattern is found [here](https://codeday.me/en/qa/20190306/12163.html), similarly I use a this.function to pass down every object as it is parsed with "City" parameter & try to render a "WeatherCitySkyMap" component for each City.  The code after render has been tested to render such a component for each City in the cities array if I hard code let cities = [{ city: "New York" }, { city: "Baltimore" }];, but I want cities to be populated by Papa.parse step for each City parsed from my dropboxlink of a csv list of cities in NorthAmerica.

```
class CitiesMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Papa.parse(
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.dropbox.com/s/5vcoo9r60hgczd1/worldcitiespop_northamerica_nolonglat.csv?dl=1",
      {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        worker: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        step: this.updateData,
        complete: function() {
          console.log("all done");
        }
      }
    );
  }
  updateData(results) {
    cities.push(results.data, ["City"]);
    this.setState({ cities });
  }
  render(props) { 
    let filteredCities = cities.filter(cities => {
      return (
        cities.City.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.props.search.toUpperCase()) !==
        -1
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Cities">
          {filteredCities.map(City => {
            return (
              <div>
                <WeatherCitySkyMap
                  description={this.description}
                  humidity={this.humidity}
                />
                {JSON.stringify([City])
                  .replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
                  .replace(/(city)/g, "")}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CitiesMap;
```

"This pattern is found here" link uses UNSAFE_componentWillMount()), instead I try to use componentDidMount() around Papa.parse, but need the Papa.parse results.data to happen before they render like componentWillMount() would have done (or should I use shouldComponentUpdate & forceUpdate() somewhere?). I read best practices is to replace componentWillMount with constructor and super, so should I put Papa.Parse in the constructor?  I tried that and got lost.  Thanks for reading & your help in advance.

UPDATE after Domino987 answer (so far):

```
import React from "react";
import WeatherCitySkyMap from "./WeatherCitySkyMap";
import Papa from "papaparse";

import ".././Explore/Cities.css";

class CitiesMap extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);
    this.state = { cities: [] };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Papa.parse( "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/k81s5enbamijuke/worldcitiespop_northamerica_nolonglat_few.csv?dl=0",
      {
        download: true,
        header: true,
        worker: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        step: this.updateData,
        complete: function() {
          console.log("all done");
        }
      }
    );
  }
  updateData(results) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data.City]
    }));
  }
  render(props) {
    let filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(cities => {
      return (
        cities.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.props.search.toUpperCase()) !==
        -1
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="Cities">
          {filteredCities.map(City => {
            return (
              <div>
                <WeatherCitySkyMap
                  description={this.description}
                  humidity={this.humidity}
                />
                {JSON.stringify([City])
                  .replace(/[^\w\s]/g, "")
                  .replace(/(city)/g, "")}
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CitiesMap;
```

Comment: Can you show where you define cities?

Comment: I should have defined initial state of cities:[ ] as you said in your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a few misconceptions of how the component works:

1. Props are not passed to render: You can access them with `this.props`.
2. Local state is null at beginning: in your constructor write `this.state = {cities: []}`, This will prevent breaking your code if you try to access cities within render.
3. To access cities in your render and updateData use `this.state.cities`. This will let you access the current cities.
4. To update an array within the state write it like this: `this.setState(prevState => { cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data.City] });`. This will update the state immutable and will keep the previous cities.

componentDidMount is the correct way to implement a server call, side effect or Papa.parse. It will render the component without data first, but as soon as data is present, it will update it. The component will not break, because with point 2 the state will not be null and the render will still work.

I hope these remarks will help you get your code working.

// Edit
Since you ask how to implement updateData and render, here is some code:

```
updateData(results) {
  // This will not work because cities is not defined here (us this.state.cities) and you mutate the data with push
  // cities.push(results.data.city); 
  // I am not sure why you add "City" but that is in your code
  this.setState(prevState => { cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data.City]});
}
render(props) {
  // Filter will check each city in the cities array, so you have to write it like this:
  const filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(city => city.indexOf(this.props.search.toUpperCase()) !== -1);
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Great info, 3. is this correct in render and updateData?
  updateData(results) {
    cities.push(results.data, ["City"]);
    this.setState(prevState => {
      cities: [...prevState.cities, cities]
     });
   
  }
render(props) {
    let filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(this.state.cities => {
      return (
  this.state.cities.City.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.props.search.toUpperCase()) !==
        -1
      );
    });
thanks!

Comment: The url I'm parsing from has "City" as a property I want to isolate. Isn't push doing the same thing as this.setState(prevState => { cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data]}), pushing new data to the end of the array?  **[y/n]** Did you add 3rd comma "City" to this.setState(prevState => { cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data, "City"]}) to isolate "City" property as [pick of lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) does? **[y/n]** I replaced city w/ City in render. sry [my project](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14) is crashy src>UIConainers>Map>CitiesMap.js

Comment: 1. No because you have to create a new array to set the state and trigger an update(no mutation). Your call will only mutate the current object and you will see no rerender[link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). 2. I added the city because I misread. Just use result.data.City.  3. It depends on how your data looks like on how you access each part of the object.

Comment: I appreciate you for this... when you say updateData(results) won't register cities as the state of the component cities, do you mean at all & I should give up or I have to do one of these two: (1) updateData(results) { let cities = this.state.cities; this.setState(prevState => ({ cities: [...prevState.cities, cities.push(results.data.City)] }));} /*or*/ (2)  updateData(results) {this.setState(prevState => ({ cities: [...prevState.cities, this.state.cities.push(results.data.City)]}));}... I have it bound in the constructor with this.updateData = this.updateData.bind(this);

Comment: You can use both but I think you have a misconception. prevState is your current state to which you want to add the new city. So you dont have to access this.state in setState. just use prevState in setState like this: this.setState(prevState => ({ cities: [...prevState.cities, results.data.City] }));}  This will set your state. It will  create a new array with the cities in your state(prevState.cities) and adds the new city to it with ,, results.data.City].

Comment: Wow I should accept the answer because I console.log(this.state.cities) in render & it logs the array each time a new city is added! Still it crashes on map's (globe icon) change location page (top left) without rendering any City... [Here is my project again](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14) src>UIConainers>Map>CitiesMap.js. The file might be too large (200MB) + it's only N. America + I'll need to get more column properties (to tell two cities with the same name, different location apart). I should maybe get cities in a different way, or I have a bug in filteredCities.

Comment: How do I navigate to the maps screen?

Comment: press the top right inbox icon on "/", then press the globe at the bottom on "/planner", then press a small-circle landscape gif on the top left on "/map". the screen for "/mapcommunities" should be blank except for header and footer, then crash/hides header+footer & console.log("all done") as of now

Comment: I'm suddenly getting a new error which may be the problem I have to use componentWillUnmount(). _"Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method."_

Comment: I will try your app tomorrow. Yes you should set a check to the setState if the component is still visible.

Comment: I added [Prevent React setState on unmounted Component](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-warning-cant-call-setstate-on-an-unmounted-component/) after searching _"check setstate componentWillUnmount"_: but now [isMounted is an anti-pattern](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) I'll research how do something similar with a promise after I update you, made the document 9 rows x 4 properties and pasted the [fix to a cross origin resource sharing issue](https://zapier.com/learn/how-to/generate-direct-dropbox-link/) of the dropbox url